# C++ variable not passing it's value after push_back

Tags: c++, variables, g++, push-back

I'm having  a weird issue where the variables i'm declaring that are pushed back to  a `vector<vector<pixel>>` are not being actually pushed back... Take a look:

```
vector<pixel> Lignetemp;
for(int j = 0; j < InfoSup.nbL; j++){
    Lignetemp.clear();
    for(int i = 0; i < InfoSup.nbC; i++){
        int Rtemp, Vtemp, Btemp;
        cin >> Rtemp;
        cin >> Vtemp;
        cin >> Btemp;
        Lignetemp.push_back({Rtemp,Vtemp,Btemp});
    }
    Data.push_back(Lignetemp);
}
```

Pixel is defined as such:

```
struct pixel{
    int R, V, B; 
};
```

The issue is that when I try to print out Data, I get only 0's instead of the values that I `cin`
Also, I'm coding on both Windows and Linux ( g++ compilers of different versions) and namely on Ubuntu the compiler gives me these sort of warnings:

> warning: extended initializer lists only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11

Do you have an idea about a fix ? 
Thanks :)

Comment: Looks like it should work.  Can we get a compile-able [mcve]?

Comment: It should work, but as an aside, if you restricted the scope of `Lignetemp` to the inner loop, you wouldn't have to clear it. It is generally good practice to restrict scope as much as possible anyway.

Comment: @NathanOliver prior to C++11 `v.push_back({a,b,c})` was a syntax error; in this case (the type being an aggregate) you had to do `T t(a, b, c); v.push_back(t);`

Comment: @M.M Sure, but it compiling and running on windows so it must be doing something.  The op just needs to turn on c++11 on their linux build.

Comment: Psychic debugger says: `cin` has the `fail` bit set

Comment: @NathanOliver I've implemented those changes but nothing new ... Thank you however, this is getting frustrating

Answer (score 2):

> warning: extended initializer lists only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11

The warning gives you a clue.

You pass the initializer list to the `push_back` method.
Here is it:
`{Rtemp,Vtemp,Btemp}`

You can either:

1. Pass the flag, mentioned in the warning, to your compiler. How to pass it - depends on what is your build system.
2. Use explicit instantiation:

   ```
   pixel p;
   cin >> p.R >> p.V >> p.B;
   Lignetemp.push_back(p);
   ```

Comment: They could just do `cin >> p.R >> p.V >> p.B;` instead of having the temp ints

Answer (score 1):

Do as the warning suggests and add `-std=c++11` or `-std=gnu++11` to your compiler options.

The syntax `Lignetemp.push_back({Rtemp,Vtemp,Btemp});` was not added to the language until C++11.